# Выделение вводных слов при обособленном обороте

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Ранее в интернете прочитал следующее:
Если вводное слово или сочетание слов стоит в начале обособленного оборота или в конце его, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т.е. запятые выделяют оборот в целом.
Пример: *Студент вернул в библиотеку книгу, вероятно даже не прочитав ее.*

Затем наткнулся на следующее предложение, где вводное слово *однако* выделяется в начале обособленного оборота:
*Однако, распахнув пахнущую казенной краской классную дверь, он убедился, что все здесь обстояло по-старому.*
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять данное противоречие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "однако" может играть в предложении совершенно разные грамматические роли.

Обычно "однако" является вводным, если стоит в середине или в конце предложения:
*Жара и усталость взяли, однако ж, свое* (Тургенев);
*Как я его ловко, однако* (Чехов).

В начале же предложения (или части сложного предложения) или как средство связи однородных членов слово "однако" имеет значение противительного союза (его можно заменить союзом **но**):
*Однако* [= но] *пора уже прощаться.

В горы вела узкая тропинка, однако* [= но] *по ней можно было пройти только до ветхой часовни.*
[**Однако — союз, междометие и вводное слово**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/odnako-kakaya-chast-rechi.html)

*Однако, **распахнув пахнущую казенной краской классную дверь**, он убедился, что все здесь обстояло по-старому* (Фад.).
В этом предложении "однако" — это союз, а не вводное слово; после него расположен деепричастный оборот, который и обособлен двумя запятыми.

Вот похожее предложение:
Однако, ответив на этот вопрос утвердительно, он заставляет своих читателей задуматься уже над другим вопросом...

Об особенностях пунктуации вводных слов и сочетаний можно прочитать здесь:
[вводное слово и обособленный оборот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).

Answer (score 1):

Однако, **распахнув пахнущую казенной краской классную дверь**, он убедился, что все здесь обстояло по-старому.

Слово ***однако*** может быть **вводным словом, союзом и междометием.**

**ОДНАКО.** I. **союз**. Употр. **для присоединения предложений или отдельных членов предложения** (близок по значению союзу "но").  Попрощался раньше времени, о. причины не объяснил.  стесняется. О. я вас слишком хорошо знаю, чтобы полностью доверять вам. II. **вводн. сл**. Тем не менее, всё же, всё-таки. Думаю, всё будет в порядке, но будьте, о., осмотрительны. III. **межд**. (с восклиц. интонацией). Употр. для выражения удивления, недоумения, возмущения и т.п. Его недавно избрали в академики. - О.!

В начале предложения ***однако*** является **присоединительным союзом** и относится ко всему предложению, а не к деепричастному обороту, поэтому оборот обособляется запятыми с двух сторон.